# Generate database from model

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Quick one right here: I used Entity Framework's database-first approach so all the classes are automatically generated.

I am delivering the application on Monday, I was thinking that it would be better to generate the database on the first launch of the app.

Is this doable? I know it possible if you are using the code-first approach.

So I thought it is reciprocal.

If it helps I am using SQL Server 2014, Visual Studio 2015, C#, Entity Framework, Winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     var scsbCentral = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        var ecbCentral = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        ecbCentral.Metadata = "res://*/KBSCentral.csdl|res://*/KBSCentral.ssdl|res://*/KBSCentral.msl";
        ecbCentral.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        scsbCentral.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
        ecbCentral.ProviderConnectionString = scsbCentral.ConnectionString;

        var CentralContext = new KBS_CentralEntities(ecbCentral.ConnectionString);
        if (!CentralContext.Database.Exists())
        {
           CentralContext.Database.Create();
        }
```

Comment: runtime time Database creation if no database found

Comment: can you tell me where to specify the DataBase Name ?

Comment: in connection string

Comment: Never mind i totally didn't see the connectionString . Thank you Sir

Comment: quick question what is ( KBS_CentralEntities ) ?? is it the modelContext ??